# Find A Control (Inside Master Page) From Content Page, Error = NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages, content-pages

Please See The Simple Example Below For Understanding My situation.
(Attention To Comments Inside Codes)

Master Page (ASPX) :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="NiceFileExplorer.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span runat="server" id="SummaryContainer">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title" runat="server" Text="Count :"
                ToolTip="Your Download Count-Today" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics_Master"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Count_By_UserID_Today() %>"
                CssClass="lblCountInStatistics_Master" ToolTip="Your Download Count-Today"></asp:Label>
            <span style="color: white;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Today_Title" runat="server" Text="Size :"
                ToolTip="Your Download Size-Today" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics_Master"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Today" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Size_By_UserID_Today() %>"
                CssClass="lblCountInStatistics_Master" ToolTip="Your Download Size-Today"></asp:Label>
        </span>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Inherit" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

as you see i set ClientIDMode="Static".

Master Page (CodeBehind) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NiceFileExplorer
{
    public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             SummaryContainer.DataBind();
        }

        protected string Download_Count_By_UserID_Today()
        {
            //Read New Count From DataBase
            //return Count;
            return "Test";
        }

        protected string Download_Size_By_UserID_Today()
        {
            //Read New Size From DataBase
            //return Size;
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

Content Page (ASPX) :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="NiceFileExplorer.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
Conntent Page
</asp:Content>
```

Content Page (CodeBehind) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace NiceFileExplorer
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethod();
        }

        private void MyMethod()
        {
            //Add New Downloaded File Info To DataBase(); -> For Getting Count And Size Of Them Per Day

            //Here I Wand To Access Master Page Controls And Update Count And Size Lables
            //So, I Tried Codes Below Without Any Results -> How Can I Fix This ?
            var SummaryContainer = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("SummaryContainer");
            SummaryContainer.DataBind();
            SummaryContainer.InnerHtml = "<h2>Hello World</h2>";

            //After Update Those Lables Failed, I test the codes Below With Null Execption Error -> How Can I Fix This ?
            var lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title = (Label)Page.Master.FindControl("lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title");
            lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title.Text = "test";

            DwonloadFile();
        }

        private void DwonloadFile()
        {
            //A Class (Method) That Shows Download Window To My Users, So Page_Load Of Master Will Never Fire...
            //And This Is The Reason That I want to update count & size lables from content page
        }

    }
}
```

i want to DataBind SummaryContainer(a span) from content page's code-behind.
so i tried the codes below :

```
            var SummaryContainer = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("SummaryContainer");
            SummaryContainer.DataBind():
```

but i can not see new results.
After That Fail I tried to find a label's text(that label is inside Master) from content page code behind for test like below :                     var

```
lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title = (Label)Page.Master.FindControl("lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title");
                    lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title.Text = "test";
```

but i have `System.NullReferenceException` ERROR :

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

how can i fix that error and force that span to show me new results?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a project I used an interface on the masterpage:

```
((IMasterPage)Page.Master).MyProperty = "test";
```

But in your case, personally instead of putting all that on the master page, I'd put your `SummaryContainer` into a UserControl, and have another `ContentPlaceHolder`.
Then the Page_Load method will be able to access the properties, and on future pages you could have different summary info by filling that first PlaceHolder with a different UserControl.

Also debugging stupid errors, is the Null exception being thrown at `.Master.FindControl` or at `lbl.Text`?

I'm unable to debug it for myself right now, but would it be due to the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx), namely that Content Page Load comes before Master Page Load?